# NodeJS with Child_Process - How to escape my command

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, batch-file, child-process

I'm currently using nodejs with the child_process module. We're experimenting some weird comportements of batch.

Basically, we just want to copy a file using xcopy command.

For instance, we do:

```
xcopy "C:/my/path/myfile.test" "C:/my/path/mynewfile.test*" => Does not work. Windows needs backslash
xcopy "C:\my\path\myfile.test" "C:/my/path/mynewfile.test*" => Does not work. We need to escape backslash
xcopy "C:\\my\\path\\myfile.test" "C:/my/path/mynewfile.test*" => Works...
```

So I have some issues.

- Why does the source parameter of xcopy need backslash while the
  destination parameter works with slash?
- I'm using the [spawn function of the child process module](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). It seems this does not escape anything. I tried to look though the code of nodejs but well... that's not easy! Does the spawn function escape the command?
- If we do need to escape the command ourselves, then we also want to execute our commands on UNIX. So I presume the escaping method is not the same. And I would not prefer to make a

  ```
    if(window)
       escapeshellargWindow(arg)
    else if(unix)
       escapeshellargLinux(arg)
  ```

Has anyone else got these kind of issues?

Comment: Just use **single backslashes** always in the Windows command prompt. It needs no escaping (except some `wmic` commands in for-loops).

Comment: @Endoro : Thanks for the answer. However, I'm not executing these commands in the Windows command prompt. I execute them with child_process of nodejs. That's why I have these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with Windows, but my guess would be that forward slashes in the first argument might be parsed as being options to the `xcopy` command. Any following arguments won't be handled as such, and will therefore work.

As for escaping, the issue isn't so much `spawn`, but more the general way of escaping in literal Javascript strings, using `\`. So if you use this:

```
spawn('xcopy', [ 'C:\my\path\myfile.test', ... ])
```

then this is what `spawn` will receive (as `arguments`):

```
{ '0': 'xcopy', '1': [ 'C:mypathmyfile.test' ] }
```

And similarly:

```
> console.log( 'C:\my\path\myfile.test' )
C:mypathmyfile.test
```

So if you want to add a backslash to a JS string, you need to escape it:

```
> console.log( 'C:\\my\\path\\myfile.test' )
C:\my\path\myfile.test
```

But this is only necessary for *literal* strings in your code (hardcoded in your JS). For strings that are either calculated or passed in some form (like from the command line in `process.argv`), additional escaping isn't necessary.

Since `spawn` is agnostic as to what you pass to it, it won't do any escaping itself.

Answer (score -1):

I have found that using forward slash for arguments and backslash for folder boundaries
works consistently.

For Example:

xcopy /S /I /D /Y "DRIVE:\Folder1\Folder2" ".\Folder1"

Hope this helps...